# Pspice - how to fix 'Simulate' [Ubuntu]

Tags: pspice, orcad

I have tasks to do for school and after 'draw' a circuit I need to start to Stimulate, but it won't work.
If anyone knows how to fix this big thanks

[image: 1: Draw]

[image: And then]

How to fix this with OrCAD Pspice AC/DC Demo. I use ubuntu 18.04

Comment: First you need to set the simulation commands: what analysis, range, options, etc. Best look for tutorials, otherwise chances are you'll be back here with another wuestion within 5 min. And then again. It's less stressful and more productive if you learn the basics of the tool with which you're going to work. BTW: your wires are drawn wrong.

Comment: I set it to Bias Point Detail

Comment: I got error: "Unable to start application pspicead.exe"

Comment: It looks like you have problems with your installation then, which means this is no longer an electronics related question. I would suggest taking this either to the Ubuntu forums, or to the Wine team (I suppose that's what you're using).